# Is there any other optimized way to avoid XElement object into procedure?

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

To pass multiple values to a stored procedure i am using this method.

```
XElement xl = new XElement("root",
            new XAttribute("OType", "Update"),
            new XAttribute("Target", "OrderActivation"),
            new XElement("Id", id),
            new XElement("UserCode", Session["usercode"]));
```

I am passing this `xl` object to stored procedure and there i am extracting this xml object.

```
Set OType           =ExtractValue(xml,'/root/@OType');
Set Target          =ExtractValue(xml,'/root/@Target');
```

Is this tech good for use or i can use anything else which is much more optimized and faster.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking, to be honest. If you can change your stored procedure, why not just give it two parameters, OType and Target? Do you actually know if you have a performance problem? You talk about wanting to make things faster - what are your current performance results and what are your success criteria? At the moment, this question is too unclear to answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually i am passing this whole object onto procedure and extracting it there . so i am concerned about the performance both side.

Comment: But do you have any evidence that you *should* be concerned about the performance? Again, what's your current performance and what are your success criteria?

Comment: Not actual proof but at one of my server it is running slow so i want to ask is it causing that.... i know it is hard to tell i just want to get some opinion. Coz this pattern i thought by myself and don't want any performance issue with this

Comment: @Dashanan adding more xml is never a solution to "my server ... is running slow" :)

Comment: You're passing two values; regular SQL parameters should absolutely be the default here...

Comment: @MarcGravell This is just a example i have given here ..... my actual xml contains 15-20 parameters thats why i am using this.

Comment: @Dashanan 15-20 parameters is *still* better done as: parameters

Comment: @MarcGravell ....I didn't understand ....